# Algorithm to execute a function only 12% of all cases

Tags: python, algorithm, random, probability

I have a function and I want to let it do things only in 12% of the cases I call it.

I already wrote a function that works, but it's not accurate enough.

Example in Python:

```
# probability to execute the function is 50%
percent_probability = 50

frequency = 100 / percent_probability

r = random.randint(1, frequency)

if r == 1:
   my_function()
```

This works for percentages like 10%, 20%, etc. but not for 33% because it gets rounded.

How can I do this properly?

Comment: So the function needs to execute only for 12% of all the function calls? Silly question.. Do we know the upper bound during runtime (the total number function calls that will occur during the lifetime of the program)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use `random.random()` for this, like so:

```
if random.random() < anz_prozent_wahrscheinlichkeit / 100.:
   execute my function()
```

This uses floating-point maths and is therefore not restricted to integer percentages (for example, `anz_prozent_wahrscheinlichkeit = 0.1` would work correctly).

Comment: but one question... those are still only 10% steps, right? I mean no matter if I put 12% or 13%, it can only be smaller than 0.2 so its still not very accurate, right?

Comment: @MatthiasScholz: No, it's very accurate and will correctly differentiate between 12% and 13%.

Comment: are you sure? maybe i'm wrong, but random.random() only outputs 10 different numbers 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, etc. So if I compare my percentage of 0.12 with 0.1 or 0.2 it will be the same result as comparing 0.13 with 0.1, 0.2 etc. just because random.random() does output floats with only one decimal place.

Comment: sorry, i was wrong, random.random() does output a totally random float... my fault!

Answer (score 6):

This should do the trick:

```
r = random.randrange(0, 100)
if r < 12:
    my_function()
```

Comment: `random.randrange(0, 100)` would be more appropriate in this case to get 12/100 and not 12/101 probability.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest method consists in getting a random number between 0 and 1 with `random.random()` and checking whether it is smaller than 0.12. This is a general method (it also works for percentages with a decimal part…).